# Как получить название Inline кнопки в aiogram python

Tags: python, aiogram

мне надо получить текст inline кнопки, но у меня вылезает ошибка, может быть я взял не правильную команду
Мне надо взять название кнопки и при нажатии вставить название
На второй картинке я нажимаю на название бразильский бурбон и в ответе мне бот должен написать фразу с названием
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: Пример как должно выглядеть]

**Текст который должен отправляться**

```py
Coffie_sort_text='''
Вы выбрали {sort} \n
Укажите в сколько килограмм вам нужно \n
 Если вы решили выбрать другой кофе нажмите кнопку отмена 
'''
'''2 Хендлера, первый для меню с сортами, второй на нажатие кнопки Бразильский Бурбон'''
@dp.callback_query(Text("Coffie_sort_buy_button"))
async def send_random_value(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer(text.Coffie_sort_buy_text, reply_markup=Button.Coffie_sort_buy_button_menu)

@dp.callback_query(Text("Brazilian_Bourbon_Santos"))
async def send_random_value(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer(text.Coffie_sort_text.format(sort=types.KeyboardButton.text))

'''Создание кнопок и меню'''
Coffie_sort_buy_button = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Бразильский Бурбон Сантос", callback_data="Brazilian_Bourbon_Santos"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Колумбия Эксельсо", callback_data="Colombia_Excelso")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Марагоджип", callback_data="Maragogype"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Эль Сальвадор Халатенанго", callback_data="El_Salvador_Halatenango")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Антигуа", callback_data="Antigua"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кобано", callback_data="Kobano")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Маракайбо", callback_data="maracaibo"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Эфиопия Мокко", callback_data="Ethiopia_Mocha")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Йемен Моха", callback_data="Yemen_Moha"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оксака", callback_data="Oksaka")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подробнее о каждом сорте", callback_data="More about sort")]
                          ]
Coffie_sort_buy_button_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=Coffie_sort_buy_button)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/385375)

Comment: На свежую голову приходят хорошие мысли, я через пару минут отвечу на свой же вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так чтобы не писать много текста и хендлеров для бота, я сделал один хендлер на несколько кнопок спасибо ответу сверху, он меня натолкнул на хорошую мысль (и помог написать меньше кода), которую я чуть-чуть по другом сделал(из-за нехватки времени)

```
'''Текст для всех кнопок'''

Coffie_sort_text='''
Вы выбрали {sort} \n
Укажите в сколько килограмм вам нужно \n
 Если вы решили выбрать другой кофе нажмите кнопку отмена 
'''

'''Создание кнопок и клавиатуры'''

Coffie_sort_buy_button = [[InlineKeyboardButton(text="Бразильский Бурбон Сантос", callback_data="BrazilianBourbonSantos_button"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Колумбия Эксельсо", callback_data="ColombiaExcelso_button")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Марагоджип", callback_data="Maragogype_button"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Эль Сальвадор Халатенанго", callback_data="ElSalvadorHalatenango_button")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Антигуа", callback_data="Antigua_button"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Кобано", callback_data="Kobano_button")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Маракайбо", callback_data="Maracaibo_button"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Эфиопия Мокко", callback_data="EthiopiaMocha_button")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Йемен Моха", callback_data="YemenMoha_button"), 
                          InlineKeyboardButton(text="Оксака", callback_data="Oksaka_button")],
                          [InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подробнее о каждом сорте", callback_data="MoreAboutSort")]
                          ]

Coffie_sort_buy_button_menu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=Coffie_sort_buy_button)


'''Первый хендлер на команду /Coffee, показывает меню с сортами'''

@dp.message(Command("Coffee"))
async def cmd(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(Coffie_sort_buy_text, reply_markup=Coffie_sort_buy_button_menu)


'''Второй хендлер для ответа на нажатия кнопок'''

@dp.callback_query(Text(["BrazilianBourbonSantos_button","ColombiaExcelso_button","Maragogype_button", "ElSalvadorHalatenango_button","Antigua_button","Kobano_button","Maracaibo_button","EthiopiaMocha_button","YemenMoha_button","Oksaka_button"]))
async def send_random_value(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    for i in range(0, len(Button.Coffie_sort_buy_button)):
        for j in range(0, len(Button.Coffie_sort_buy_button[i])):
            if callback.data == Button.Coffie_sort_buy_button[i][j].callback_data:
                await callback.message.answer(text.Coffie_sort_text.format(sort=Button.Coffie_sort_buy_button[i][j].text))
```

Теперь при нажатии на любую кнопку у меня будет выводится текст с разными названиями сортов[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, это то, что тебе надо.
В массиве кнопок указываешь параметр callback_data

```
buttons = [
        [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", callback_data="opt_first_option"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2", callback_data="opt_second_option")
        ],
        [types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Подтвердить", callback_data="opt_finish")]
    ]
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=buttons)
```

Тогда нажатие кнопки будет равносильно отправлению сообщения с текстом, который ты указал в callback_data. Доставать можно просто вот так:

```
#вызываем функцию которая покажет нам кнопки
@dp.message(Command("test"))
async def cmd(message: types.Message):
    user_data[message.from_user.id] = 0
    await message.answer("Выберите опцию", reply_markup=get_keyboard())

#реагируем на кнопки  
@dp.callback_query(Text(startswith="opt_"))
async def callbacks(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    user_value = user_data.get(callback.from_user.id, 0)
    action = callback.data.split("_")[1]

    if action == "first_option":
#do smth
    elif action == "second_option":
#do_smth
    elif action == "finish":
#do_smth
    await callback.answer()
```

Comment: Спасибо попробую, а можно из кнопки  параметр  text  взять?

Comment: я не понимаю что означает эта строчка '''action = callback.data.split("_")[1]''', можете объяснить?

Comment: она значит, что мы разделяем строку по нижнему подчеркиванию и берем вторую часть

Comment: то есть если у нас callback_data = "opt_finish", то action = finish

Comment: Спасибо, я понял

Comment: Не за что! Отметь мой ответ как решение, если не сложно)

Comment: параметр text из кнопки взять насколько знаю нельзя

Comment: Я смог взять, но твое решение мне помогло, сейчас добавлю свое решение

Comment: Отлично, рад помочь